# Pass data from one controller action to another view in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I require to pass a variable from one controller action  to javascript in another view..

In controller Action A:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection args)
    {
        var obj = new ProjectManagernew();

        var res = new ProjectViewModelNew();
        try
        {
            UpdateModel(res);
            if (obj.AddUpdateOrderField(res))
            {
                ViewBag.RecordAdded = true;
                ViewBag.Message = "Project Added Successfully";
                TempData["Name"] = "Monjurul Habib";
            }
            return View(res);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ModelState.AddRuleViolations(res.GetRuleViolations());
            return View(res);
        }
    }
```

In another javascript:

```
function gridA() {
   var message = '@TempData["Name"]';
   $('#mylabel').text(message);
}
```

Only Tempdata works But not the first time its working from the second time after iam calling the action controller

1. I want to temp data to work rom the first time
2. I want t clear the data after using

Comment: Can you show your full controller action A code?

Comment: is your javascript inside the same view that receives the ProjectViewModelNew?

Comment: Its in a different view but recieves ProjectViewModelNew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your javascript is inside the same view that takes the ProjectViewModelNew, you can use a different type for your view, for example you can use composition:

```
public class MyCompositeClass
{
  ProjectViewModelNew ProjectViewModel{get;set;};
  string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and then your action method would be:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection args)
{
    var obj = new ProjectManagernew();

    var res = new ProjectViewModelNew();

    var myView = new MyCompositeClass();
    try
    {
        UpdateModel(res);
        myView.ProjecViewModel = res;
        if (obj.AddUpdateOrderField(res))
        {
            ViewBag.RecordAdded = true;
            ViewBag.Message = "Project Added Successfully";
            myView.Name= "Monjurul Habib";
        }
        return View(myView);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //ModelState.AddRuleViolations(res.GetRuleViolations());
        return View(myView);
    }
}
```

and your js would be:

```
function gridA() {
   var message = '@Model.Name';
   $('#mylabel').text(message);
}
```